# Find the "$n$-th integral" $\overbrace{\int \cdots \int}^{n} p(x) e^x d^{n}x$ and its coefficients in terms of the coefficients of $p(x)$

Tags: calculus

Find the "$n$-th integral" $\overbrace{\int \cdots \int}^{n} p(x) \mathrm{e}^x \mathrm{d}^{n}x$ and all the coefficients of the solution in terms of all the coefficients of $p(x)$.

I didn't find any correct symbols to write "$n$-th integral", so I just wrote the way it can maybe make sense.

Just to clarify, I was doing it for fun and was curious if this is possible to do.

Before I came to the $n$-th generalization, I first started with solving the following integral:
$$\int p(x) \mathrm{e}^x\mathrm{d}x$$ where $p(x)=\alpha_{k}\cdot x^k+\alpha _{k-1}\cdot x^{k-1}+\cdots +\alpha _{1}\cdot x+\alpha _{0}$

To solve this integral I used integration by parts, $\int uv'=uv-\int u'v$, where $u=p(x)\implies \mathrm{d}u=p'(x)\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}v=\mathrm{e}^x\mathrm{d}x \implies v=\mathrm{e}^x$.
Then we can use integration by parts again and again until $p^{(k+1)}(x)=0$, and write down:

$$\int p(x) \mathrm{e}^x\mathrm{d}x=p(x)\mathrm{e}^x-\int p'(x)\mathrm{e}^x\mathrm{d}x=p(x)\mathrm{e}^x-p'(x)\mathrm{e}^x+\int p^{(2)}(x)\mathrm{e}^x \mathrm{d}x=\cdots=\left(p^{(0)}(x)-p^{(1)}(x)+p^{(2)}(x)-\cdots +(-1)^{n}\cdot p^{(k)}(x)\right)\cdot \mathrm{e}^x=\left (\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{k}\cdot p^{(k)}(x)\right)\cdot \mathrm{e}^x$$

I will write the new polynomial as $q_{1}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{k}\cdot p^{(k)}(x)$, and $q_{n}(x)$ will be the $n$-th polynomial solution: $\overbrace{\int \cdots \int}^{n} p(x) \mathrm{e}^x \mathrm{d}^{n}x=q_{n}(x) \cdot \mathrm{e}^x$.
I'm not interested about the ``Constants Polynomial'' that we get from taking the integral $n$ times.

For the first integral, I would like to find the coefficients of $q_{1}(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}(-1)^{k}\cdot p^{(k)}(x)=\beta _{k}\cdot x^k+\beta _{k-1}\cdot x^{k-1}+\cdots +\beta _{1}\cdot x+\beta _{0}$.

That means to find every $\beta_{k}$ in terms of all the coefficients of $p(x): \alpha_{k}$

**Example**:
For $p(x)=\alpha _{2}\cdot x^2+\alpha _{1}\cdot x+\alpha _{0}$, $q_{1}(x)$ will be:
$q_{1}(x)=p^{(0)}(x)-p^{(1)}(x)+p^{(2)}(x)=\alpha _{2}\cdot x^2+\alpha _{1}\cdot x+\alpha _{0}-2\alpha_{2}\cdot x-\alpha _{1}+2\alpha _{2}=(\alpha _{2})\cdot x^{2}+(\alpha_{1}-2\alpha_{2})\cdot x+(\alpha_0-\alpha_{1}+2\alpha_{2})$ 
That means $\beta _{2}=\alpha _{2};\beta _{1}=\alpha_{1}-2\alpha_{2};\beta _{0}=\alpha_0-\alpha_{1}+2\alpha_{2}$ 

Then if it was possible to find all the coefficients of $q_{1}(x)$, generalize it to find all the coefficients of the n-th polynomial $q_{n}(x)$ for the solution of the "n-th integral" $\int \overbrace{\cdots}^{n} \int p(x) e^xd^{n}x=q_{n}(x) \cdot e^x$, in terms of the coefficients of $p(x):\alpha_k$ 

I will not be surprised if I had any mispelling, or mathematical mistakes, you're welcome to fix it. 

I have no idea how interesting this will be for anyone else like it is for me, but if you are able to make it, it will be very cool. Or even if you can do something completely different but related to it which is also interesting, I would like to see it. 

For the tags I added Calculus. If there are more tags needed to add, you can add them.

Comment: Possibly this will be of interest to you (a formula for the "n-th integral" of a function): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration.